# Please explain C# syntax to a vb-er

Tags: c#, vb.net, syntax, ternary-operator

I have the following code snippet:

```
        // Notify the source (the other control).
        if (operation != DropOperation.Reorder) {
            e = new DroppedEventArgs()
            {
                Operation = operation == DropOperation.MoveToHere ? DropOperation.MoveFromHere : DropOperation.CopyFromHere,
                Source = src,
                Target = this,
                DroppedItems = srcItems
            };
            src.OnDropped(e);
        }
```

I do not understand the
`Operation = operation == DropOperation.MoveToHere ? DropOperation.MoveFromHere : DropOperation.CopyFromHere` line.

Can someone explain it?  For the record...dropOperation is an enum.
Can you give vb syntactical equivalent is all I need.

Seth

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason it's hard to understand is due to the fact that you're unfamiliar with the ternary operator ?:. Basically what it does is evaluate an expression, and return one of two value depending on whether the evaluation returned *true* or *false*.

For example, the following expression will return "true" if the boolean is true, and "false" elsewise:

```
bool test = false;
string testString = test ? "true" : "false";
```

It does in fact exist in VB.NET as well - expressed a bit differently though. These two statements in respectively C# and VB.NET are in fact the same

```
Dim s As String = If(True, "kek", "lol")
string s = true ? "kek" : "lol";
```

The difference between IIf and the tenary operator is that IIf will always evaluate both the second and third parameter because IIf is a function instead of an operator. For this reason the tenary operator is much to prefer.

*Note*: The tenary operator was added in VB 9, so if you're using previous versions you'll have to rely on the IIF function for this functionality.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that (I have not coded VB.NET in a couple of years). This one is definitely to prefer over the `IIf` function given that is uses short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: +1 for suggesting If instead of Iif!!!! Also, If has the advantage of being type-safe, you don't need to do casts.

Comment: I think that you have a typo in the code. I don't see an `Iif`, only an `If`.

Comment: It's not a typo, If() is VB9's ternary operator.

Comment: Thanks Qua...that did it.  And thanks for the lesson on ternary op for vb.  I am very familiar with iif.  Glad to know there is now a short-cicuiting version.
Seth

Comment: The real typo is in the first sentence of the answer: "tenary". ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
If (operation = DropOperation.MoveToHere) Then
    Operation = DropOperation.MoveFromHere
Else
    Operation = DropOperation.CopyFromHere
End If
```

Comment: Sorry for downvote, but Qua's answer should really score above this one.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: that's the strangest reason I've ever heard, but given the fact that I've lost only 2 points, I won't make a fuss about it :-)

Comment: I always come back and check these.  Do a no-op edit to your post and I can undo the downvote now.

Answer (score 3):

[Obligatory wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).  I gave up on mentioning this link in a comment, so here it is in an answer.  You can replace uses of the ? operator with calls to the IIF function:

```
Operation = IIF(operation = DropOperation.MoveToHere, DropOperation.MoveFromHere, DropOperation.CopyFromHere)
```

Note that they are not strictly equivalent, since the IIF **function** evaluates both the true and the false case, whereas the ? **operator** only evaluates the case it returns.

Comment: If() is strictly equivalent though. There's no reason to use Iif unless you're stuck with an old version of VB. Iif is also not type safe.

Answer (score 3):

It is *sort of* equivalent of the [`IIf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d.aspx) function in VB.NET (see Brian's comment):

```
Operation = IIf(operation = DropOperation.MoveToHere, _
                DropOperation.MoveFromHere, _
                DropOperation.CopyFromHere)
```

In C# this is called the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), and is a sort of shortcut for a simple if/else statement.

Comment: Note that they are not strictly equivalent, since the IIF **function** evaluates both the true and the false case, whereas the ? **operator** only evaluates the case it returns.

Comment: @Brian: hence the text *sort of equivalent*, but still your comment adds good value.

Comment: If() is strictly equivalent though. There's no reason to use Iif unless you're stuck with an old version of VB. Iif is also not type safe.

Answer (score 2):

This is using the [`?` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28VS.80%29.aspx) for conditional assignment. This line is basically syntactic sugar for:

```
// C# expanded example
if (operation == DropOperation.MoveToHere)
{
   Operation = DropOperation.MoveFromHere;
}
else
{
   Operation = DropOperation.CopyFromHere;
}
```

Which, in VB, would be equivalent to:

```
If operation = DropOperation.MoveToHere Then
   Operation = DropOperation.MoveFromHere
Else
   Operation = DropOperation.CopyFromHere
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the conditional operator, it is very similar to VB's [`IIf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28VS.71%29.aspx) function:

> Returns one of two objects, depending on the evaluation of an expression.

```
Public Function IIf( _
   ByVal Expression As Boolean, _ 
   ByVal TruePart As Object, _ 
   ByVal FalsePart As Object _ 
) As Object
```

In this particular example the `IIf` function would be written like this:

```
Operation = IIF((operation = DropOperation.MoveToHere), _
    DropOperation.MoveFromHere, _
    DropOperation.CopyFromHere)
```

Comment: Shouldn't use the IIF function, as it evaluates both expressions. The tenary operator doesn't.

Comment: VB9 has a new ternary If operator that's a better match.

Comment: @Qua: It's fine in this case.  The true and false part are just enums.

Comment: That's true, and without focusing too much on optimization it's worth mentioning that the tenary operator is a ... operator which means no function overhead as opposed to IFF

Answer (score 1):

```
operation == DropOperation.MoveToHere ? DropOperation.MoveFromHere : DropOperation.CopyFromHere
```

This is called the ternary operator. It's basically a short way of writing:

```
if (operation == DropOperation.MoveToHere)
  return DropOperation.MoveToHere;
else
  return DropOperation.CopyFromHere;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `?:` construct is the ternary operator, basically an inline `if (x) y else x`.  The benefit of the inline is seen here in that it is assigned immediately to a variable.  You can't do that with an if statement.

Answer (score 1):

C# Bloggers use the "?" a lot. Look this code:

```
int Foo(int x, int y){
return x==y? 10: 11;
}
```

Is equal to:

```
int Foo(int x, int y){
if (x==y)
return 10; 
else
return 11;
}
```

Just read the well explained Donut's answer!!

("VB-er" I like the term)

Answer (score 0):

It's called the [ternary operator.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28VS.80%29.aspx) I don't think it exists in VB but it's basically just a shorthand for an if/else.